# Create hive tables to different schemas

Tags: hive, avro

**I have this hdfs structure:** 
root/folder1/a1.avro
root/folder1/b1.avro
root/folder2/a2.avro
root/folder2/b2.avro

**a1, a2  - have schemaA

b1, b2 - have schemaB**



**I want to:**
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE in hive to all data 
or
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE to a data & CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE to b data.

**How do I do that?** 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK,I created 2 Hive external tables, Table_A for schema A and Table_B for Schema B.

Once I have 2 tables, I run 2 sets of "alter table add partition" statements:

Alter table table_a add partition …  'root/folder1/a1.avro';
Alter table table_a add partition …  'root/folder2/a2.avro';

Alter table table_b add partition …  'root/folder1/b1.avro';
Alter table table_b add partition …  'root/folder2/b2.avro';

Comment: What happend if I have only 1 hive table? Will the table be crashed?